# python3 arp-scan and mac parsing

Tags: python, python-3.x, mac-address, arp

I'm trying to parse the mac addresses from arp-scan output. 
There's an example:

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def get_active_hosts():
    with Popen(['sudo', 'arp-scan', '-l', '-r', '5'], stdout = PIPE) as proc:
        mac_list = re.compile('\s+(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]){2})\s+')
        mac_list = mac_list.findall(proc.stdout.read().decode('utf-8'))
    return mac_list
print(get_active_hosts())
```

But I got this output:

```
[('4a:c3:26:0e:85:d0', '85:', '0')]
```

What's going on ? How to capture only mac addresses without this trash:

[('85:', '0')]

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

`findall` is returning all of the matching groups that it found. Groups are declared using a set of parentheses. Your regular expression contains three groups as follows:

```
(([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]){2})
([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:)
([0-9A-Fa-f])
```

So now hopefully you understand why `findall` gives you three matches, and why they look like they do.

The solution here is to declare these extra groups (the ones you don't want) to be **non-capturing** by putting `?:` after the opening parenthesis as follows:

```
mac_list = re.compile('\s+((?:[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}(?:[0-9A-Fa-f]){2})\s+')
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the documentation on the findall method:

> re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, as a list of strings. The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are
>   returned in the order found. **If one or more groups are present in the
>   pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the
>   pattern has more than one group.** Empty matches are included in the
>   result.
>
> Changed in version 3.7: Non-empty matches can now start just after a previous empty match.

Pay attention to the bold text. You have more than one groups in the pattern:

- (([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]) => '4a:c3:26:0e:85:d0'
- ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}:) => '85:'
- ([0-9A-Fa-f]) => '0'

And as documentation said you get a list of tuple with captured groups.

To get only full mac address you need specify non-capturing parenthesis into regexp. The *re module* documentation says:

> (?:...)
>   A non-capturing version of regular parentheses. Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, but the substring
>   matched by the group cannot be retrieved after performing a match or
>   referenced later in the pattern.

So, fix all non-main parenthesis (which not capture the entire mac address).